# pandas_datareader cant print date on x axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-datareader

In following plot date is not showing on x axis what do to show date time stamp

```
import  numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as web
start=datetime.datetime(2014,1,8)
end =datetime.datetime(2019,1,8)
Tesla=web.DataReader('TSLA',"iex",start,end)
Ford=web.DataReader('F',"iex",start,end)
Tesla["open"].plot(label="Tesla",title="opening Price",figsize=(16,8))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dataframe index is created as dtype object or string, let's convert index to DatetimeIndex using `pd.to_datetime`:

```
import  numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as web
start=datetime.datetime(2014,1,8)
end =datetime.datetime(2019,1,8)
Tesla=web.DataReader('TSLA',"iex",start,end)
Ford=web.DataReader('F',"iex",start,end)

#Change Telsa index to datetime dtype
Tesla.index = pd.to_datetime(Tesla.index)

#Let's do Fords too
Ford.index = pd.to_datetime(Ford.index)

Tesla["open"].plot(label="Tesla",title="opening Price",figsize=(16,8))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: it worked thanks  instead of typing every  is their any way to improve code  like declare variable

Comment: @AmitkumarJadhav No.  I really can't think of anyway to improve that.